Gcs fuse with google buckets - Too many open files error with java app
I have a java spring boot application deployed as kubernetes application in GCP.
I use GCS fuse to access Google Cloud Storage buckets with the Cloud Storage FUSE CSI driver because it allows me to mount Cloud Storage buckets as a file system so that applications can access the objects in a bucket using common File IO operations.
When i tried to rename or to move a not empty directory in my java applications that contains more than 20 files. I got this error in my app container:
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /volume/mydirectory -> /volume/mydirectoryTmp : Too many open files
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:457)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)

and this error in fuse side-car container:
fuseops.RenameOp error: too many open files

I tried many solutions suggested in web that not work for me like a suggest to use the following flag
--rename-dir-limit 1000 

After a lot of time lost, i found a solution that i want to share it with you because it was a headake for me to resolve it.

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  More specifically, what does the copy operation look like, and are you making sure to close files once you're done with them?

This error occurs when you try to rename or move a not empty directory with code like this:
Files.move(dir, wrkDir, REPLACE_EXISTING);

the way that works for me, is to create the destination directory and to move file by file and then remove source directory.
If you error is on rename method do the same solution.
So, i change the given line code  by this one and it was resolved.
public static void moveFilesInDirectory(Path sourcePath, Path targetPath) throws IOException {

    if (!Files.exists(sourcePath) || !Files.isDirectory(sourcePath)) {
        throw new IOException("Source directory does not exist or is not a directory: " + sourcePath);
    }

    if (!Files.exists(targetPath)) {
        Files.createDirectories(targetPath);
    }

    try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(sourcePath)) {
        for (Path path : directoryStream) {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(path)) {
                Path targetFilePath = targetPath.resolve(path.getFileName());
                Files.move(path, targetFilePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            }
        }
    }

    Files.delete(sourcePath);
}

This solution logic can be the same for other language than java.
